# Jquery Mobile Odata example not working

Tags: jquery-mobile, odata

I have just started using jQuery Mobile with OData, and this is the first example. I just copied the HTML file given in the example and it worked perfectly on my laptop and on my phone. After a couple of days I checked the file on my laptop and it had stopped working.

This is the code I copied as-is and it worked:
http://code.google.com/p/share-some-code/source/browse/Odata_jqm.html

And now it does not work; I suspect the JSON stream is messed up.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the link the place where you originally downloaded the example? Or can you point us to the original source you used? Also, have you checked if the server is returning the JSON you expect?

Comment: Yes that is where i downloaded the code

Comment: to answer my own question all it needed was &$format=verbosejson instead of &$format=json